# Users can't click on buttons

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/hampani/pen/MWjKede

The buttons that the user can't click on are "Button 1" and "Button 2".

```
.video-header .viewport-header {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do with the display: flex attribute.

Comment: no its the `main::before` remove it and it works

Comment: Please include a [mre] on Stack Overflow itself, not only on an external site like CodePen. See [ask], second bullet under "Help others reproduce the problem", where it says "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the z-index.

Try adding these changes:

```
.video-header, .video-header video, .video-header .viewport-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.video-header .viewport-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you put buttons on the screen but you didn't tell what to do when someone clicks it so to tell this you should use onclick=""

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick='insert_function_here'>Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick='insert_function_here'>Button 2</button>
  </div>
```

you should write a javascript function

Answer (score -1):

In your code, in  element you use ::before. You have to add just z-index and your code works.

```
main::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: -100vh;
  z-index:-1;
}
```